# android finish() vs activity.finish()

Tags: android

I am working on some legacy code for an android app, and in some activities when they want to finish the activity they write

```
finish()
```

and in other places they write

```
activity.this.finish()
```

what is the difference?

Comment: They are the same :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`actvity.this` is transparent in an Activity class, because it references to itself, so you can call a class method both using and not using it as in Java